# How to prevent user from just typing spaces in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am new to C and I am currently dealing with array functions.

There is my problem, I am asking user to input his username, and I would like to allow number, char, and space as first character. So I created a function to prevent user from just typing spaces using a do-while loop. 
At the first iteration, if I only 4 spaces type  the 'filter' works perfectly, but if I type 4 spaces again, the function considerer thoses spaces as good. 
Here is the code:

```
void user_name (char *name) {
    int nb_space = 0;
    char buffer;
    do {
        printf("Player, please type your username \n");
        memset(name,'\0', sizeof(*name));
        scanf("%99[^\n]", name);// Using REGEX to prevent buffer issues with '\n'
        for(int i=0;i< sizeof(name);i++){
            if (name[i] == (char) ' '){
                nb_space++;
            }
        }
        while ((buffer = (char) getchar()) != '\n' ? buffer != EOF : false);//Using 'getchar' to empty the buffer 
    } while (nb_space == strlen(name));//I tryed to replace strlen with sizeof but nothing have changed
    first_maj(name);
}
```

And there is the caller:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char name[100];
    user_name(name);
    printf("your name: %s\n",name);//to check what we got 
}
```

The "first_maj" function is just a fonction which capitalizes the first char of each separated word. This is the output I got (I represente the spaces with '.':

```
Player, please type your username
....
Player, please type your username
....
your name: ....
```

The program should asks again and again until the user types a character after the 4 spaces, or simply types directly characters. Exemple of wished output (dots = spaces):

```
Player, please type your username
.....
Player, please type your username
...john.rambo
your name: ...John.Rambo
```

Where is my mistake ? I could not figure out what is wrong in this code.

**EDIT #1**

Here is the capitalize function "first_maj" if it is important to find my mistake:

```
void first_maj (char name[]){
    if (isalpha(name[0])){
        name[0]= (char) toupper(name[0]);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<strlen(name);i++){
        if (isalpha(name[i]) && name[i-1] == ' '){
            name[i] = (char) toupper(name[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

My question was about the iteration issue, not exactly the size of the array, but thank to you i could realize about other mistake.
After reviewing the code with the debug function, i finally found the mistake I was looking for: I just forgot to reinitialize nb_space within the loop:

```
void user_name (char *name, int length) {
        int nb_space;
        char buffer;
        do {
            nb_space = 0;
            printf("Player, please type your username \n");
            memset(name,'\0', sizeof(*name));
            scanf("%99[^\n]", name);// Using REGEX to prevent buffer issues with '\n'
            for(int i=0;i< sizeof(name);i++){
                if (name[i] == (char) ' '){
                    nb_space++;
                }
            }
            while ((buffer = (char) getchar()) != '\n' ? buffer != EOF : false);//Using 'getchar' to empty the buffer 
        } while (nb_space == strlen(name));//I tryed to replace strlen with sizeof but nothing have changed
        first_maj(name);
    }
```

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `sizeof(*name)` is wrong, and so is `sizeof(name)`.

Comment: Neither `sizeof(*name));` nor `sizeof(name));` is of any use in a function which is passed a pointer, because the only information you have, is a pointer, and its type.

Comment: You need to have an size_t or int parameter in both the user_name() and first_maj() functions. Because those functions are getting only a pointer to a buffer of chars, they have no way of knowing the size of the buffer. You must pass the length in. So to call user_name: `user_name(name,100)` and the prototype should be `void user_name( char *, int length)`

Comment: @Chimera: "*You need to have an size_t or int parameter in both the user_name() and first_maj() ...*" Why to `first_maj()`?

Comment: @alk Because first_maj() is being passed a pointer to an array. The length isn't known. Look how it's being called from user_name().

Comment: @alk Granted, first_maj() isn't well written and *shouldn't* need to know the length because the passed in array is NULL terminated. But my comment speaks to the actual implementation of first_maj().